# Recommend some books or online sites for self- learning Prana Pratishta techniques

Tags: mantras, worship, book-recommendation, pranapratishtha

What are some good books (in Bengali, English, Hindi or Sanskrit) for self-learning the method of [Prana Pratishta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha) (invoking life-force of Deites) on Yantras, idols etc?

I am looking for books or even online sites with (audio/video) demonstrations.

Comment: I'm aware that some good books are available for the purpose.Its just that i don't know their names.Also please don't say-Ask your Guru.Because if i do my Guru will get angry on me thinking that i'm wasting my time or that i'm going wayward. :)

Comment: You already know the answer that your guru will give and yet you think your mind is right. Read the *Taittiriya Upanishad* Chapter I. ii. 1. on pronunciation. Also the *Taittiriya Samhita* (II. iv. 12.). It tells the story of the dire consequences of chanting a mantra without the proper pronunciation. In it the god Tvashtri accents the first syllable of *Indra-satru* instead of the last syllable. As a result, it yields the opposite result he was to get and leads to his complete destruction...

Comment: I now know how to do it. But u can add an answer if u want @AnuragSingh

Comment: I don't know how can u add it. I just said that because it seemed to me u want to post an answer. Anyways, i don't really need an answer now, as i have many books now that teach how to do pranapratishta.@AnuragSingh

Comment: @Anurag Singh How many pages?  Can't they be photocopied and shared?

Comment: @AnuragSingh You can just say  what you have said in the comments because it is answering the question. Add chapter number and verse numbers for respective devatas. It's enough. Comments are not for answering. Answers are for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"lagu pran pratishtha" is the title of a video on prana pratishta by Yogi from kaulantak nath peeth, it's in Hindi though.

https://youtu.be/LS_9a6LurlA

Comment: Yes this is the slim Yogi i was talking about. :) Are u a disciple from their parampara BTW?

Comment: Can pranpratishta be used on everyday objects, weapons etc?

Comment: I don't have a guru '-(

Comment: Prana pratishta is done on Yantras,idols/images, stones on water-pot or even on flower. On weapons also yes.

Comment: Who's your guru?

Comment: i have two Gurus. But i don't want to name them. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70741/discussion-between-steam-punk-and-rickross).

Comment: In the video there is a reference to the actual method of pranpratishta

Answer (score 3):

It is very hard to find the prana pratishta and stapana mantras online.

I have asked pundits in my area they are not willing to give the mantras saying that only brahmans are qualified to do the sthapanas etc., . Told them I am also a brahman but not a karmakandi yet.

Comment: Thanks for ur response..But now i actually  know how to do pranapratishta of deities..